# Save Data from TextBoxes

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to save Data from two Textboxes and an DatePicker for my UWP App, but I dont know which way is the best. 
I created an Class with the variables I want to save and tried to save it into an XML File, but that didnt work.
This is how my class looks like:

```
public class KalenderClass
{
    public string Termin { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Datum { get; set; }
    public string Person { get; set; }
}
```

And this is what i tried:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
```

KalenderClass kc = new KalenderClass();
kc.Termin = TerminTextBlock.Text;

I hope you can help me out.

Comment: Please share the code which you tried!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the data locally in XML, you can do this in UWP:

```cs
public async Task SaveDataInLocalFile(KalenderClass data)
{
    var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var dataFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("DataFile.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(KalenderClass));
    using (var stream=await dataFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream.AsStream());
        serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
    }
}
```

Try not to use `FileStream`, because accessing files by path is restricted in UWP. The recommended way is to use `StorageFile`.

Each UWP application has its own corresponding application folder, you can directly access it through `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` and create files.

Comment: Thank you very much! But where do I put the Data from the TextBoxes?

Comment: I want to save the data through an Button from TextBoxes

Comment: You mentioned Button, then you can put this method call in Button's Click event callback. Before calling this method, you can create a new instance of `KalenderClass` and fill in its property values, just like you did in the question description